# Authlogic throws errors on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic, heroku

I am trying to stage an app on Heroku that uses the Authlogic plugin. The Logs show me this error. I first thought there is a problem with the gem version, but I tried several: 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3.

But I tried deploying the [authlogic example](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) but it throws the same error.

Thank you for your time.

```
Processing UserSessionsController#new (for 188.27.118.88 at 2009-10-03 01:34:08) [GET]
Parameters: {"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"user_sessions"}
Rendering template within layouts/account
Rendering user_sessions/new

ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `login' for #<UserSession: no credentials provided>) on line #12 of app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:
9:         = f.text_field :login
10:       %li
11:         = f.label :password, "Password:"
12:         = f.password_field :password
13:       %li
14:         = f.label :password, "Remember me:"
15:         = f.check_box :remember_me

app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:12:in `_run_haml_app47views47user_sessions47new46html46haml'
haml (2.2.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:163:in `call'
haml (2.2.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:163:in `form_for'
haml (2.2.3) lib/haml/helpers.rb:542:in `call'
haml (2.2.3) lib/haml/helpers.rb:542:in `haml_bind_proc'
haml (2.2.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:169:in `form_for'
app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:4:in `_run_haml_app47views47user_sessions47new46html46haml'
haml (2.2.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
haml (2.2.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
haml (2.2.3) rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
/home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
/home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:25:in `call'
/home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (0.12.6) lib/eventmachine.rb:240:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (0.12.6) lib/eventmachine.rb:240:in `run'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/server.rb:150:in `start'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:173:in `send'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:173:in `run_command'
thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:139:in `run!'
thin (1.0.1) bin/thin:6
/usr/local/bin/thin:20:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/thin:20

Rendering /disk1/home/slugs/54799_a9ae7e8_77bb/mnt/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you run all migrations on the staging server? It looks to me like a model class is missing an attribute, which is often a symptom of an un-run migration.

Comment: That seems the most likely case.

Comment: Yep you are right, I'm officially an idiot. Can't tell you how much time have I spent debugging the thing.