# Authlogic throwing errors on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, heroku

Yes, I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513208/authlogic-throws-errors-on-heroku).

This is what I'm getting in my production.log:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `password' for #<User:0x2b0ddb58cdc0>) on line #11 of app/views/users/new.html.erb:
8:         </p>
9:         <p>
10:           <%= f.label :password, "Password:" %><br />
11:           <%= f.password_field :password %>
12:         </p>
13:         <p>
14:           <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password again:" %><br />
```

When I try:

```
$ heroku rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get:

```
yeqynzfiku already exists
(in /disk1/home/slugs/109616_e6df6f2_8837/mnt)
Couldn't drop yeqynzfiku : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  must be owner of database yeqynzfiku
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "yeqynzfiku">
```

I don't know what this means. I've also tried

```
$ heroku rake db:reset
$ heroku rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
$ heroku rake db:migrate
$ heroku rake gems:install (for what it's worth)
```

Everything works fine locally, both in development and production modes. I have a .gems file in my app, and when I first pushed to Heroku it seemed to install AuthLogic and Paperclip just fine.

Stumped. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Sounds like you solved it, but with problems like this I find it handy do do a `heroku restart`.

For example, after running migrations with `heroku rake db:migrate` the app needs to be restarted before it will see those new columns.

Comment: This was the key when I was having the same issue. Cheers

Comment: "heroku restart" is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `db:reset` try `db:migrate VERSION=0` and `db:migrate`.
I think they have issues with reset because it tries to drop the db.
Also, you don't need to put `RAILS_ENV=production` it's the default AFAIK...

Comment: BTW authlogic makes troubles in heroku, I had to put version info in .gems first, and after sometime had another issue, so I just installed it as plugin...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I did a `heroku restart` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, had something to do with lots of things in the .gitignore file. Should have cleared it before pushing to Heroku.